# Blending in an Ant Render with Newspaper Background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

How do I make it look like the ant is actually on the newspaper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Project a shadow.
- Blur the ant according to the blur on the background. Probably you need to put the ant in another place, so both stay in the focused area.

Comment: I'd add better scale to. Without knowing the size of this sudoku board the ant looks oversized.